# How can I complete the pre departure confirmation of react components (including class components and function components)？

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I have searched the answer of this question for many times, and I know this can be solved by the **Prompt** comnponent in react-router v4. But I use the version 6.x of it. What is the substitution of the component **Prompt** in v6?

Comment: `Prompt` and all browser navigation blocking has been removed in RRDv6 for the meantime. You could try using a custom router and history object in order to use [`history.block`](https://github.com/remix-run/history/blob/main/docs/api-reference.md#historyblockblocker-blocker).

Answer (score 0):

There is no substitution so far: [prompt-is-not-currently-supported](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#prompt-is-not-currently-supported). `Prompt` and `usePrompt` where present up to v6.0.0-beta.6 but were removed in the stable v6 release.

The general [advice](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/8139#issuecomment-954425560) is to remain on v5 if you really need this feature or re-design your user experience without blocking behaviour.

Comment: That's a bad news. Is there really no other way besides demotion? I'm a newcomer to react, and I don't feel that I'm as good as Vue in compatibility. Especially the update of react router.

Comment: Beside Drew's suggestion above of using a custom router (but since you're new at React that might be quite challenging) I guess your best option is to downgrade to v5. There's a guide for upgrading to v6 on the [docs](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#upgrade-to-react-router-v6), which you could try following backwards. And here are the [docs for v5](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start). Depending on how complex your use case it might be a relatively easy refactoring.

Comment: Thranks for your answer for me, I'll downgrade the react-router to v5, but I've tried this function use event listening in `useEffect` named 'beforeunload', its also a method even if it is not elegant.